# What is the difference between EBNF and CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar, ebnf, ebnf-syntactic-exception

I understand that EBNF can be used to express Context Free Grammar, but is there any difference between the two?

I am asking because there are questions that ask to convert EBNF to CFG, but as of my current understanding, they look same. Therefore, what is the intention behind this conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EBNF can be used to write a context-free grammar.

The latin alphabet can be used to write English.

Pascal can be used to express an algorithm.

A "context-free grammar" is an abstract thing which you can write out in EBNF form for machine input.  The actual context-free grammar is a mathematical object.  It has standard notation, but the standard notation is really for human consumption.

Answer (score 3):

Summary: EBNF is not directly equivalent to the CFG formalism, but many EBNF grammars can be mechanically converted.

---

A context-free grammar is a four-tuple of:

- A set of nonterminals `V`
- A set of terminals Σ which is disjoint from `V`
- A set of productions of the form

`v → ω`

where `v` is an element of `V` and `ω` is an element of `(V ⋃ Σ)*` (that is, a possibly-empty string of terminals and non-terminals.

- A starting symbol `S` which is an element of `V`.

(See [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Formal_definitions) and its references. There is another equivalent formalism which uses the set of non-terminals `V` and an alphabet `A` which is the union of `V` and `Σ`.)

An early concrete syntax for CFGs was proposed by John Backus in 1959 in order to describe the `Algol` programming language; this formalism is generally referred to as [`Backus-Naur Form`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus_Naur_Form), a name proposed by Donald Knuth, recognizing the contributions of Algol report co-author Peter Naur. The main difference between BNF and the CFG formalism above is that productions with a common left-hand side are abbreviated using the `|` symbol:

`v → ω1 | ω2

    ⇒

      v → ω1

      v → ω2`

However, in practice the use of regular operators, particularly repetition operators like the Kleene Star, has proven to be much easier to write and to understand. A number of extensions to BNF were proposed and used in various grammars, especially by Niklaus Wirth. In particular, it became common to use a form of extended BNF in standard protocol documents, both RFCs (IETF internet standards) and various ISO standards. These formalisms were eventually "standardized" as [Extended BNF, ISO/IEC 14977](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=26153) and the somewhat similar [Augmented BNF, RFC-5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234).

In order to convert EBNF to the CFG formalism, it is necessary to expand all uses of repetition -- including finite repetition--, alternation and optionality operators into primitive form, which requires the introduction of new non-terminals. Also, both EBNF and ABNF allow specifications which may be impossible to convert to CFG, including restrictions written in English. (See the first note in my answer to [Ebnf – Is this an LL(1) grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175248/ebnf-is-this-an-ll1-grammar/20179940#20179940))

Comment: "ABNF allow specifications which may be impossible to convert to CFG".
I'm not sure about that. Case insensitivity can be translated as alternation. Conversion of alternation itself and repetition is straightforward. There are no caveats such as set difference provided by ISO EBNF. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Przemek: any ABNF which makes use of  `prose-val` (top of p. 12 of the standard).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Unlike ABNF and RBNF, the standard for EBNF allows for exceptions which mean that it can be used to define non context free languages.

Proof:

1. The language of L1 = {a^n b^n a^m | n, m ≥ 0} is generated by:

   L1 ::= X,A

   X ::= "a",X,"b" | Emptystring

   A ::= A,"a" | Emptystring
2. The language of L2 = {a^n b^m a^m | n, m ≥ 0} is generated by:

   L2 ::= A,X
3. L 1 ∩ L 2 = {a^n b^n a^n | n ≥ 0} is not context free by the pumping lemma since, for a given p ≥ 1 we can choose n > p such that s = a^n b^n a^n is in our
   language and we cannot pick any substring q of s such that q is of length p, s = xqy
   for some strings x and y and x q^n y ∈ L 1 ∩ L 2 (since q would have to take in at least one a and should take in the same number of as on the left as on the right).

   P ::= L1 − L2

   {a^n b^n a^n | n ≥ 0} is the language of Q where

   Q ::= L1 − P